# Converting circular structure to JSON error on tRPC

Tags: typescript, types, next.js, trpc.io

Using the t3-stack (Next, tRPC, Prisma, Next-auth, Typescript)

```
tRPC failed on undefined: TRPCError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'RequestHandler'
    |     property 'client' -> object with constructor 'PrismaClient'
    --- property '_fetcher' closes the circle
```

repo link: https://github.com/gabrielforster/my-portfolio (develop branch)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same error, in my case it was because I wasn't destructing my `input` value. Otherwise, it looks like it tries to serialize the entire context, including your PrismaClient etc.

Changing:

```
    .query(async (input) => {
```

to:

```
    .query(async ({ input }) => {
```

fixed my issue

```
  dataQuery: publicProcedure
    .input(QueryInputValidator)
    .output(QueryOutputValidator)
    .query(async ({ input }) => {
      return requestBackendEnv<QueryOutput>({
        url: "query/",
        method: "POST",
        body: input,
      });
    }),
```